# Freeware Network Monitoring Software

Tags: open-source

The company I work for is quite small. We use Fortinet firewall switch to do all our routing, etc. But, on the reporting side it's not very good. What we are looking for is some free software which will accomplish the following:

1. Report which websites are being visited, and how long.
2. Provide alerts when bandwidth utilization hits..say 80%.

Those are the primary requirements. Anything else, in terms of monitoring, would be great.

Also, we currently don't have a domain which makes it a little more difficult. However, each user has their own login on their own machines.

Comment: Freeware and Free Software refers to different things. Former is gratis and later is libre. Make it clear in the title